# Deploying Laravel 5.2 to a shared hosting domain. Kernel routing problems

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, laravel-5

I am deploying a Laravel application to shared hosting. The Larevel files sit in a folder called PGM in the user folder and the public files sit in the public folder.

Paths:

```
/home/name/PGM/

/home/name/public_html/
```

I have edited the index.php to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../PGM/bootstrap/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../PGM/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I am however getting the following error message in the log:

> [17-Aug-2016 19:01:46 UTC] PHP Warning: 
>   include(/home/parsonsgreenmedi/PGM/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/parsonsgreenmedi/PGM/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412

I am using PHP 5.6

Comment: have you run `composer install`?

Comment: You might find some solutions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory